# What is the advantage of using triple dot (...) notation for adding conditional map entry in Dart2?

Tags: dart

So I had a piece of code that looks like this:

```
    Map<String, dynamic> params = {
             param1:val1
             //rest of params
        };
     if(someCodnition){
        params[newKey]=newValue
     }
```

I have been  told that its better to use `...` notation, however it could not be explained why is it better besides look of code (which is worst IMHO).

So the code should be like this:

```
    Map<String, dynamic> params = {
             param1:val1,
             //rest of params
            if(someCondition) ... {
               newKey:newValue
            }
        };
```

1. Is it really better to do it that way?
2. Is there any performance gain?
3. Wouldnt that create new Map that contatenates current `params` state with `{newKey:newValue}` - which would be worst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only one new key, then you should do:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> params = {
     param1:val1,
     //rest of params
     if (someCondition) newKey:newValue
 };
```

If there is more than one, I'd probably use the version you showed.
The compiler should (eventually, if not yet) be able to recognize that you are inlining a map literal and just insert the elements directly in the outer map without creating an intermediate map.